# Java - create nested tree view from csv file

Tags: java, arraylist, tree, nested

I've searched through similar questions and can't find a clear solution, so was hoping someone could help. 
I'm fairly new to Java and trying to do the following, but have got a little bit stuck. 
Problem: 
I have a CSV file with three fields: String, int, String
It's an organisation list showing 140 people in my dept, along with their manager, and I want to create a nested tree structure showing the whole org.

The CSV fields are: employee, numberOfDirectReports, manager
e.g. a sample might be:

```
Bob, 5, Dave

Dave, 2, Alice

Sam, 0, Bob
```

so this tells me that Alice is at the top of the tree, and Dave reports to her. Dave himself has 2 direct reports, one of these is Bob. Bob has 5 direct reports, one of these is Sam. Sam has no direct reports.

Alice

```
- Dave
     - DavesOtherReport

     - Bob

         - Sam

         - BobsOtherReport

         - BobsOtherReport

         - BobsOtherReport

         - BobsOtherReport
```

What i've done so far is to create a class called Employee, with three variables String employeeID, int numDirectReports, String manager
I've created an ArrayList called employeeList, which contains 140 Employee instances.

I can print out the list of employees and their manager. 
But what I want to do is iterate through the list / array (apologies if i'm mixing my terminology a bit) and produce something like the above tree structure for the entire population.

Any ideas? 
Do I need to create another intermediate data structure for this? if so, how do I initialise and then populate it? 
Or can I print the kind of tree i'm after using just the employeeList I've populated already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is to update each employee to add inside it a list of the employees directly below it. (I'm busy writing code to explain it :))

```
public static class Employee{
        String name;
        int numberOfDirectReport;
        String manager;
        List<Employee> directReport;

        public Employee(String name, int numberOfDirectReport, String manager) {
            this.name = name;
            this.numberOfDirectReport = numberOfDirectReport;
            this.manager = manager;
            this.directReport = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public boolean add(Employee employee) {
            return directReport.add(employee);
        }

        public String toString(){
            return toString("");
        }

        public String toString(String prefix){
            String result = prefix + name + "\n";
            for(Employee child : directReport){
                result += child.toString(prefix+"\t");
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // step 1: loading employees, to be replace by actual call to CSV reader
        HashMap<String, Employee> employees = new HashMap<>();
        employees.put("Bob", new Employee("Bob", 5, "Dave"));
        employees.put("Dave", new Employee("Dave", 2, "Alice"));
        employees.put("Sam", new Employee("Sam", 0, "Bob"));
        employees.put("Alice", new Employee("Alice", 2, null));

        // step 1.2: adding fake employees for test completion
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            String name = "BobOtherReport"+i;
            employees.put(name, new Employee(name, 0, "Bob"));
        }
        employees.put("DaveOtherReport", new Employee("DaveOtherReport", 0, "Dave"));

        // step 2: link employees together
        for(Employee employee : employees.values()){
            if(employee.manager != null){
                // we retrieve the manager from the map and add this employee in the list inside it
                employees.get(employee.manager).add(employee);
            }
        }

        // step 3: display the top one. Either you loop on the map to find the one without manager, either you specify it
        System.out.println(employees.get("Alice").toString());
    }
```

which gave output

```
Alice
    Dave
        Bob
            BobOtherReport0
            BobOtherReport2
            BobOtherReport1
            BobOtherReport3
            Sam
        DaveOtherReport
```

Step 2 can be updated to check that the manager is known before adding the link to avoid NPE. Another solution would be to create the manager on the fly and add it in the map in this same fragment.

```
if(employee.manager != null){
                // we retrieve the manager from the map and add this employee in the list inside it
                Employee manager = employees.get(employee.manager);
                if(manager != null){
                    // manager has been loaded before
                    manager.add(employee);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Wisthler, this is great, but when I try to substitute in the call to the CSV reader, and read in the values from the file, it throws a null pointer exception. clearly i'm buggering something up, but i'm not able to figure out what exactly.

Comment: try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile)){
   String line = br.readLine();
   while(line != null) {
    String[] attributes = line.split(",");
    String empID = attributes[0];
    int numCounselees = Integer.parseInt(attributes[1]);
    String counsellor = attributes[2];
    
    employees.put(empID, new Employee(empID, numCounselees, counsellor));

    line = br.readLine();
   }
  }catch(IOException ioe) {
   ioe.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println(employees);

Comment: i'm fairly sure i'm reading the data from the CSV file, because I can print to the console the list of names in the file,e.g.
{john.smith=john.smith
, george.best=george.best
}
NB: i've substituted the names above to protect the innocent

Comment: but i then get this error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at tutorialOne.Employee.main(Employee.java:78)

line 78 contains 
System.out.println(employees.get("denis.law").toString());

where denis.law is my root node, i.e. the top of my org tree, like Alice in the example

Comment: the value in the employees.get("...") need to match the one in the csv at 100%, no casing issue, no space issue, nothing different. Educated guess is that it's not the case for you :)

Comment: Thanks Wisthler, It's a good shout, and I had thought about that, but as far as I can tell there is no white space, no odd characters, and i pasted the value directly from the csv file into the "get" clause. I'm trying to use the eclipse debugger to see if i can get more info on where it's failing / why it's not finding the value in the hashmap, but i'm not that familiar with the debugger, so it's slow progress.

Comment: Have I populated the hashmap properly?
I replaced the manual puts in your example above with a while loop that reads from the csv, so perhaps i've done it wrong and not populated the map properly, which is why the get clause can't find the name

Comment: try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile)){
   String line = br.readLine();
   while(line != null) {
    String[] attributes = line.split(",");
    String empID = attributes[0];
    int numCounselees = Integer.parseInt(attributes[1]);
    String counsellor = attributes[2];
    
    employees.put(empID, new Employee(empID, numCounselees, counsellor));

    line = br.readLine();
   }
  }catch(IOException ioe) {
   ioe.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: not sure why the code above wasn't pasted in as formatted in this comment (i'm also new to stackoverflow, so it's a learning curve)

Comment: i actually commented out the line 
System.out.println(employees.get("firstname.surname").toString());
and still get the null pointer exception, so i think it's actually the line below that's finding the error: 
employees.get(employee.manager).add(employee);

I've added a line directly below this in the for loop to see which name, and manager pairs are being added, and it stalls after 46 of the 143 records. the same 46 are printed, so I suspect the data itself is causing a problem, but i don't know how to drill into the issue and see which line is causing it to choke

Comment: i think i've spotted which record the "add" is choking on, but i can't figure out why

Comment: ok, I think i'm closer to figuring out what the issue is. 
The "Root" of the tree, i.e. the senior manager, let's call her Alice, she has a manager herself, but that manager is external to this org (i.e. Alice is the most senior person in this list, but Alice has a record herself, which lists her own manager, let's call him Adam. Adam appears nowhere else in this list. He is not in the "name" column, and so has no "key" in the map. Not sure how I resolve this.

Comment: I need somehow to allow for records that have a manager who is not in the list. There are a handful of other "orphan" employees, whose manager is not in the same org, and so won't be listed as a key in the map either. any ideas how to populate the map to avoid this issue?

Comment: split the line ```employees.get(employee.manager).add(employee);``` in two. Retrieve first the manager and check that it's not null before calling the add on it. Second approach would be to create the manager on the fly if not found with ```map.getOrDefault()```

Comment: I thought the if statement was already checking if the manager was null, i.e. 
for(Employee employee : employees.values()){
            if(employee.manager != null){
                // we retrieve the manager from the map and add this employee in the list inside it
                employees.get(employee.manager).add(employee);
            }
        }

so should it not skip out of the if clause and back into the for loop if it comes across the record that shows "Alan" as manager, since "Alan" is not a key in the hashmap?

Comment: in fact, i'm not sure the if clause is being evaluated properly, because i tried changing it to 
 if (employee.manager != "Alan") {
    // we retrieve the manager from the map and add this employee in the list inside it
    //employees.get(employee.manager).add(employee);
    System.out.println("Manager is: " + employee.manager);
   }

Comment: the above code prints out "Manager is Alan" but surely when the for loop reaches the record with the manager = Alan, then the IF clause employee.manager != "Alan" should be false, and we shouldn't attempt to execute the code in the IF block.

Comment: @Stephen you need two if. The existing one check if a manager is defined for the current employee. The new one that I was talking about is to check if the manager is known to us or external. I've put an update on my solution to show the two if. Have alook.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Wisthler. 
the code is now working, and I can print a lovely little org tree. 
Have a great day, and good vibes to you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you correctly, you would have a class like this:

```
public class Employee {
    private String employeeID;
    private String manager;
    int numDirectReports;
    private List<Employee> employeeList;

...
}
```

A few comments:

- Why not declare `manager`as an `Employee`? wouldn't it be simpler to use?
- field `numDirectReports` is redundant: it's value should be equal to `employeeList.size()`.
- A same employee should not appear twice in the `employeeList` of some manager.

So I would rather declare a class as follows:

```
public class Employee {
    private String employeeID;
    private Employee manager;
    private final Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<>();

    public String getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(String employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    public Employee getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setManager(Employee manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public Set<Employee> getEmployeeSet() {
        return new HashSet<>(employeeSet);
    }

    public void addEmployee(Employee e) {
        employeeSet.add(e);
    }
}
```

Now, to load the CSV while building the tree as the same time, I would use a `Map<String,Employee>`:

```
    Map<String,Employee> allEmployees = new HashMap<>();
    for (String[] record: csvRecords()) {
        String id = record[0];
        int redundant = Integer.parseInt(record[1]);
        String managerId = record[2];
        Employee emp = allEmployees.get(id);
        if (emp == null) {
            emp = new Employee();
            emp.setEmployeeID(id);
            allEmployees.put(id, emp);
        }
        Employee manager = null;
        if (managerId != null && managerId.length() > 0) {
            manager = allEmployees.get(managerId);
            if (manager == null) {
                manager = new Employee();
                manager.setEmployeeID(managerId);
                allEmployees.put(managerId, manager);
            }
            manager.addEmployee(emp);
        }
        emp.setManager(manager);
    }
```

UPDATE

If you need the number of direct reports, you could add a method:

```
public int numberOfDirectReports() {
    return employeeSet.size();
}
```

Comment: THanks so much to both of you.
oddly, Maurice, when I type 
Map<String,Employee> allEmployees = new HashMap<>();
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token, which disappers if i remove the semicolon (but this would then not be valid syntax)
I get an error in eclipse

Comment: @Stephen this is strange indeed. Check the statement that precedes.